# Getting a dynamic element under a div tag

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="product-item">
    <div class="image">
        <img src= "a URL that changes" data-code="1234567" alt= "product">
```

Hi all,

I am new to web scraping with Selenium. My question is that how can I scrape the number "1234567" inside data-code= when the tag img is something that changes dynamically (1234567 also changes dynamically). I believe it is related to getting the children tag under the div tag.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add few more lines of html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `tag img is something that changes dynamically`? Do you mean that **value** of `src` & `data-code` changes?

Comment: give some HTML code examples of  'tag img is something that changes dynamically'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the `HTML` you have provided to scrape the number **1234567** inside `data-code` atribute you can use either of the following line of code :

- **`css_selector`**

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.product-item > div.image > img").get_attribute("data-code"))
  ```
- **`xpath`**

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-item']/div[@class='image']/img").get_attribute("data-code"))
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the xpath solution! I was actually doing something similar, and I believe I cannot get the "1234567" is because I use get_attribute("data-code=") instead of get_attribute("data-code").

Answer (score 0):

Below line in java prints the number 1234567 irrespective of the tag name.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.product-item > div.image *:nth-of-type(1)")).getAttribute("data-code"));
```